# Magento 2 Knockout JS data binding issue

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

[image]

My Magento 2 check out page looks like this, seems it does not bind the knockout JS data. When I check the JavaScript console, there are no errors or issues.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Are you asking why the shipping 'not yet calculated' is not giving you a result? More specifically, what isn't working the way you want it to and have you edited any code trying to get something in there? Knockout JS is working as the price and qty are both pulled in using knockout binding, so it's not a global problem with knockout, but possibly more specific to what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

I Fix this issue,

just add the below code your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module> ModPagespeed off </IfModule>
```